# rails using sql variables in find_by_sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, find-by-sql

I have this query:

```
SET @current_group = NULL; 
SET @current_count = 0; 
SELECT user_id, MIN( created_at ) as created_at, CASE WHEN @current_group = user_id THEN @current_count WHEN @current_group := user_id THEN @current_count := @current_count + 1 END AS c 
FROM notifies 
G    ROUP BY user_id, c 
ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0 , 10
```

If i launch it it works

but if i put it in a find_by_sql method like:

```
Notify.find_by_sql("SET @current_group = NULL; SET @current_count = 0; SELECT user_id, MIN( created_at ) as created_at, CASE WHEN @current_group = user_id THEN @current_count WHEN @current_group := user_id THEN @current_count := @current_count + 1 END AS c FROM notifies GROUP BY user_id, c ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0 , 10")
```

It returns this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @current_count = 0; SELECT user_id, MIN( created_at ) as created_at, CASE WH' at line 1:
```

How can i do?

thanks

Comment: I've never seen such a thing. Is this a proper MySQL query or some other dialect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `find_by_sql` only works with a single *[statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax.html)*.

Setting variables happen in separate statements.  `set` specifically is in the [Database Administration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/set-option.html) section, number 12.4.4, and `select` is in [Data Manipulation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html) section, number 12.2.7.  Consoles (usually) allow multiple statements, and keep the variables around, but ActiveRecord queries do not.

To allow multiple statements, I *think* you have to maintain a persistent connection with the database, which Rails doesn't do (edit: normally).  But I'm not certain about that - if anyone else knows, I'd love a more definite reason.

**Edit:** actually, I have a solution for you.  Try this:

```
items = YourModel.transaction do
  YourModel.connection.execute("SET @current_group = NULL;")
  YourModel.connection.execute("SET @current_count = 0;")
  # this is returned, because it's the last line in the block
  YourModel.find_by_sql(%Q|
    SELECT user_id, MIN( created_at ) as created_at, CASE WHEN @current_group = user_id THEN @current_count WHEN @current_group := user_id THEN @current_count := @current_count + 1 END AS c 
    FROM notifies 
    GROUP BY user_id, c 
    ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0 , 10
  |)
end
```

All those run in a single transaction, and any variables / settings inside the transaction block will persist between queries.  You're still bound to a single statement per query though.  There might be a way to do it without an actual transaction wrapping the whole set, but I haven't looked for it - most likely you want one, or you now have a very specific thing to look for if you know you don't.

Enjoy!

Answer (score -2):

Accordingly to the API it is this syntax:

```
Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id,  start_date]
```

So you might want to try putting it into an array instead of using parenthesis.

```
Notify.find_by_sql ["SET @current_group = NULL; SET @current_count = 0; SELECT user_id, MIN( created_at ) as created_at, CASE WHEN @current_group = user_id THEN @current_count WHEN @current_group := user_id THEN @current_count := @current_count + 1 END AS c FROM notifies GROUP BY user_id, c ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0 , 10"]
```

Comment: Sam @current_group and @current_count aren't ruby variables but MYSQL variables. if i launch this in phpmyadmin it works. But with rails find_by_sql method no. So the question is: how can i do that?

Comment: oh I see. Just glossed over it.